# How to add an error notice with jquery?

Tags: javascript, status-messages

Been trying to add a custom error notice with jquery, but so far the div looks funky

```
jQuery('h1').prepend('<div class=\"error\">Start</div>');
```

Any tips how to get this to work? As I understand Drupal uses the error div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal uses `messages` as the 'base' class for messages so this should work:

```
jQuery('h1').prepend('<div class="messages error">Start</div>');
```

Note that you shouldn't escape double quotes inside a string unless the string is actually wrapped in double quotes.